# Find match between multiple lines and different files in R

Tags: r, loops

I have one file (file:1) that contains some gene and corresponding values and there are different files in a folder (folder:1) that files also contain genes and corresponding values. I want to compare the row's value of (file:1) to the folder's file i.e first value of file:1 will compare to 1st file of the folder and second value will compare to the second file.

```
file:1 
gene1  1.22
gene2  0.90
gene3  1.91 .....

folder:1
gene1.csv
gene2.csv
gene3.csv

gene1 contain information 
gene1  0.99
gene1  1.00
gene1  2.02
```

Comment: To clarify, in **file1** `"gene1 1.22"`, and we want to compare this to **gene1.csv** file's 1st row which is `"gene1 0.99"`, and results is: they have different values?

Comment: @zx8754 yes, gene1.csv contains different values of gene1, I want to compare how many time I got up and down values from file1's value (1.22) for gene1.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to reproduce your setup, but something like below should get you started:

```
x <- read.table("file1")

apply(x, 1, function(i){
  y <- read.table(paste0("folder1/", i[ 1 ], ".csv"))
  sum(y$containInformation == i[ 2 ])
})
```

Comment: Will you please explain how 4th line (sum(y$containInformation == i[ 2 ])) is working?

Comment: @ritz 4th line is comparing 1.22 for gene1 to all values in gene1.csv, if they are same it gives TRUE, then sum is just summing all the TRUE (1) values. So we know how many of gene1.csv is same as our 1.22. You can change the conditions to "how many more than, less than" using ">" or "<" instead of "==". Hope it is clear.